# keyvalue-command: A Key changes Another

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, key-value, expkv

I have a keyvalue-command `\cmd[map]` that produces 
[image]

Now I need another key `stepstrokes=true`, that produces 
[image] 
That means: Text of 'map' is gray now and the 'stepstrokes' overlay (and 'startpoints' or 'arrows' [see below] is futhermore an option).

I hope, this is understandable.

The solution is probably simple to program, but I have no idea now.

**MWE:**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\tikzset{
CommonStyle/.style={baseline=0em, anchor=base, remember picture},
SymbolTextColor/.style={text=#1},
SymbolTextColor/.default={black},
}


\newcommand\TheSymbol{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[] (tempcoordinate-0) {S0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheMap{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[] (tempcoordinate-\n) {S0(\n)};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheStepStrokes{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[text=gray] (tempcoordinate-\n) {S0(\n)};
\node[] at (tempcoordinate-\n) {S\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheArrows{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=red] at (tempcoordinate-0.south){x0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheStepArrows{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=red] at (tempcoordinate-\n.south){x\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheStartpoints{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=blue] at (tempcoordinate-0.north){y0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheStepStartpoints{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=blue] at (tempcoordinate-\n.north){y\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}



\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
  ,data color = \mycolor
  ,boolTF map = \mymapTF
  ,boolTF stepstrokes = \mystepstrokesTF
  ,boolTF arrows = \myarrowsTF
  ,boolTF startpoints = \mystartpointsTF
}
\newcommand\cmd[1][]
{%
 \begingroup
 \ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
 \mycolor\color{}% hier stepstrokes
 \mymapTF{\TheMap}{\TheSymbol}%
 \mystepstrokesTF{\TheStepStrokes}{}%
 \myarrowsTF{\myarrowsTF{\mymapTF{\TheStepArrows}{\TheArrows}}{NOTHING}}{}%
 \mystartpointsTF{\mystartpointsTF{\mymapTF{\TheStepStartpoints}{\TheStartpoints}}{NOTHING}}{}%
\endgroup
}

% For the presentation: 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=white, colframe=white, fontupper=\ttfamily,
enhanced, borderline south={1pt}{-2pt}{black}}
\begin{document}
%Test:  \TheMap


\begin{tcblisting}{}
(1) \cmd[map]         
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(2) \cmd[map, arrows]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(3)  \cmd[map=false, arrows]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(4)  \cmd[map=false, arrows=false]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(5)  \cmd[map, startpoints]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(6)  \cmd[map, arrows, startpoints]
\end{tcblisting}        

\begin{tcblisting}{}
For the last one I have no idea
\cmd[map=true, stepstrokes=true]        
\end{tcblisting}        

\texttt{it should look -only- something like that:}
\TheStepStrokes \\

\texttt{That means: Text of 'map' is gray now and the 'stepstrokes' overlay; and 'startpoints' or 'arrows' is futhermore an option.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't want to evaluate `map` at all if `stepstrokes` is true, because the output of `stepstrokes` does already include the output of `map`. The following does this by putting the test of `\mymapTF` inside the false branch of `\mystepstrokesTF`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\tikzset{
CommonStyle/.style={baseline=0em, anchor=base, remember picture},
SymbolTextColor/.style={text=#1},
SymbolTextColor/.default={black},
}


\newcommand\TheSymbol{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[] (tempcoordinate-0) {S0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheMap{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[] (tempcoordinate-\n) {S0(\n)};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheStepStrokes{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle]
\node[text=gray] (tempcoordinate-\n) {S0(\n)};
\node[] at (tempcoordinate-\n) {S\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheArrows{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=red] at (tempcoordinate-0.south){x0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheStepArrows{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=red] at (tempcoordinate-\n.south){x\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\newcommand\TheStartpoints{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=blue] at (tempcoordinate-0.north){y0};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\TheStepStartpoints{\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[CommonStyle, overlay]
\node[text=blue] at (tempcoordinate-\n.north){y\n};
\end{tikzpicture}}}


\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
   data color = \mycolor
  ,boolTF map = \mymapTF
  ,boolTF stepstrokes = \mystepstrokesTF
  ,boolTF arrows = \myarrowsTF
  ,boolTF startpoints = \mystartpointsTF
}
\newcommand\cmd[1][]
{%
 \begingroup
 \ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
 \mycolor\color{}% hier stepstrokes
 \mystepstrokesTF{\TheStepStrokes}{\mymapTF{\TheMap}{\TheSymbol}}%
 \myarrowsTF{\myarrowsTF{\mymapTF{\TheStepArrows}{\TheArrows}}{NOTHING}}{}%
 \mystartpointsTF{\mystartpointsTF{\mymapTF{\TheStepStartpoints}{\TheStartpoints}}{NOTHING}}{}%
 \endgroup
}

% For the presentation: 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{colback=white, colframe=white, fontupper=\ttfamily,
enhanced, borderline south={1pt}{-2pt}{black}}
\begin{document}
%Test:  \TheMap


\begin{tcblisting}{}
(1) \cmd[map]         
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(2) \cmd[map, arrows]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(3)  \cmd[map=false, arrows]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(4)  \cmd[map=false, arrows=false]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(5)  \cmd[map, startpoints]        
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{}
(6)  \cmd[map, arrows, startpoints]
\end{tcblisting}        

\begin{tcblisting}{}
For the last one I have no idea
\cmd[map=true, stepstrokes=true]        
\end{tcblisting}        

\texttt{it should look -only- something like that:}
\TheStepStrokes \\

\texttt{That means: Text of 'map' is gray now and the 'stepstrokes' overlay; and 'startpoints' or 'arrows' is futhermore an option.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking not bad. But did you check, that ``\cmd[map=false, stepstrokes=true, arrows, startpoints] ` has no effect. Should produce the same like Number 6, but allow with respected `arrows=true` and `startpoints=true`

Comment: @cis if you use `arrows=true` and `startpoints=true` the overlays will be added (they did in my short test, and I thought that's what you wanted).

Comment: @cis though I'd not use a different output routine for `map=true` and for `stepstrokes=true`, but use one unified macro there and only use a different output routine when neither of them is true. The output routine should then check whether the `stepstrokes` overlay should be applied or not.

Comment: Ah, `\cmd[map=true, stepstrokes=true, arrows, startpoints] `. Mmmh, yes: so far so good.